# Error connecting to Exchange 2019 EWS with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2019

I migrated from Exchange 2016 to 2019.  I have a PowerShell script I use to connect into exchange using EWS to access the inbox of a user.  It keeps failing on connect.  I tried to see if there is anything different from 2016 to 2019 but am coming up empty.  Here is the code I was using to connect to 2016

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
$User_Domain = "domain"
$Password = "user_pass"
$EWS = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService -ArgumentList "Exchange2013"
$EWS.Url = "https://mail19.server.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
$Username = "username"
$EWS.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $Password, $User_Domain

$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($EWS,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
```

When I run the last line I get this error:

```
Exception calling "Bind" with "2" argument(s): "The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
At line:1 char:1
+ $inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($EWS,[Mic ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceRequestException
```

This worked fine on my old 2016 exchange server. I am wondering if there is something on exchange I need to tweak or if the code needs tweaked to be able to work with exchange 2019.  I am able to access the EWS url and log in with the username/password.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after scouring the internet it seems to be an issue with Exchange 2019 enforcing TLS1.2. I added the following line to the powershell script and the error goes away

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
```

Hopefully that helps someone else

Comment: This TLS thing is a change the industry made almost two years ago for all SSL websites. So, not really a Powershell Specific issue or feature or limitation. It's an industry protocol change. ['google to enforce tls'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27google+to+enforce+tls%27&t=h_&ia=web)...   [Microsoft to enforce tls](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27microsoft+to+enforce+tls%27&t=h_&ia=web), many other articles on the topic.